# If no internet my app is stopped & unfortunately, helloworld has stopped

Tags: android

If no internet app is stopping forcely

```
webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        final Activity activity = this;
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.canGoBack();
        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }

        public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
            // Check to see if there is a progress dialog
            if (progressDialog == null) {
                // If no progress dialog, make one and set message
                progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
                progressDialog.setMessage("Loading please wait...");
                progressDialog.show();
                // Hide the webview while loading
                webview.setEnabled(false);
            }
        }

        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            // Page is done loading;
            // hide the progress dialog and show the webview
            if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                progressDialog = null;
                webview.setEnabled(true);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error){
            //Your code to do
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Internet Connection May not be active Or " + error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    // The URL that webview is loading
    webview.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Add this method on your class

```
    protected boolean isOnline() {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

if you want to know about the Internet Connection status use below code

```
    if(isOnline()==true)
    {
        //Internet Connected!  //do your action here

    }
    else
    {
        // "No Internet!
    }
```

Hope it will helps!

Answer (score 0):

Following use code to check internet connection

```
ConnectivityManager conMgr =  ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

{  
        NetworkInfo netInfo = conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        if (netInfo == null)
        {

            Description.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            new AlertDialog.Builder(WelcomePage.this)
            .setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setMessage(
                    getResources().getString(
                            R.string.internet_error))
            .setPositiveButton("OK", null).show();
    }
    else
    {
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(WelcomePage.this, "", "Loading...", true,
                false);
        new Welcome_Page().execute();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you at least format your code before you copy paste it here

Comment: It's not a mistake it's just a matter of properly presenting your code. Please format it